# как в словаре выводить рандомно ключи без повторений

Tags: python, случайные-числа, dict

появляются повторно ключи в цикле как лучше исправить это ?

```
import random

def main():

    citizen_contru={'украина':'киев',
                    'россия':'москва',
                    'беларусь':'минск',    
                    'молдова':'кишинев',
                    'ирландия':'дублин',
                    'португалия':'лессабон',
                    'греция':'афины',
                    'австрия':'вена',
                    'литва':'вильнюс',
                    'сербия':'белград',
                    'чехия':'прага',
                    'италия':'рим',
                    'испания':'мадрид',
                    'польша':'варшава',
                    'румыния':'бухарест',
                    'венгрия':'бухарест',
                    'германия':'берлин',
                    'норвегия':'осло', }
    
    print('\t\t\t\tУгадайте столицу')
    print()
    print('Проверим ваши знания географии. Надо написать столицу страны ')
    Kol_otvet=5
    prav_otv=0
    nepr_otv=0
    while  True:
        
        
        a=random.choice(list(citizen_contru.keys()))
        print(a,end=' ' )
        b= input( )
        
        if citizen_contru[a]==b:
            prav_otv+=1
            Kol_otvet-=1
        else:
            
            nepr_otv+=1   
            Kol_otvet-=1 
        
        if Kol_otvet==0:
            print('Вы ответили правильно - ',prav_otv)
            print('Вы ответили не правильно - ',nepr_otv)
            break
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте возьмем аналогию с колодой карт:

`random.choice` - это вы перетасовали колоду карт, вытащили карту из середины, посмотрели, вставили обратно. Никто не гарантирует, что вам снова не попадется эта же карта. Вы можете где-то помечать, какие карты уже выпадали, засовывать их обратно при повторном выпадении, но чем больше вы карт уже вытащили, тем чаще придется это делать.

Чтобы было без повторений, вам нужно перетасовать колоду, и последовательно снимать карты сверху колоды, пока колода не закончится. Значит берете список ключей, передаете в `random.shuffle`, потом по перетасованному списку ключей последовательно идете, пока список не закончится.

Дальше уже смотря что вам нужно - или заканчивать игру, или перетасовать еще раз, но в любом случае будут уже выходить те ключи, которые попадались раньше (вплоть до того, что первым ключом может оказаться последний ключ из предыдущего прохода).

```
countries = list(citizen_contru.keys()

random.shuffle(countries)

for a in countries:
    b= input(a + "? ")
    
    if citizen_contru[a]==b:
        prav_otv+=1
        Kol_otvet-=1
    else:
        
        nepr_otv+=1   
        Kol_otvet-=1 
    
    if Kol_otvet==0:
        print('Вы ответили правильно - ',prav_otv)
        print('Вы ответили не правильно - ',nepr_otv)
        break
```

Либо через `random.sample` выбираете нужное количество случайных стран, и так же по ним последовательно идете (в аналогии с картами - вытащить n случайных карт из колоды, по одной их показать игроку). Тогда даже считать количество ответов не нужно будет, главное чтобы оно не оказалось больше общего количества стран.

```
for a in random.sample(citizen_contru.keys(), Kol_otvet):
    b = input(a + "? ")
    
    if citizen_contru[a] == b:
        prav_otv += 1
    else:
        nepr_otv += 1
    

print('Вы ответили правильно -', prav_otv)
print('Вы ответили не правильно -', nepr_otv)
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй прогонять через random choices и string.  [Ссылка на примеры](https://flexiple.com/python/generate-random-string-python/)

Либо по id ключей через numpy unique

Comment: Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).